# Python popen issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, popen

I am working on using multi-threaded approach to automated test cases. I am using threading and popen.

I have some batch files that I call from the python script:

```
cmdStr = "Example.bat cmdArg1 cmdArg2"

cmd = shlex.split(cmdStr)

p = Popen(cmd,shell=True)
```

The batch file in turn calls another exe(foo.exe).

When I run this code snippet using python the foo.exe cannot find a dll file.

However, I don't get the error while using the command prompt to run the same batch file.

What can be the possible issues?

Comment: Well, there may be many options... 
My first thought is that foo.exe has relative path to dll.

As you said you don't get the error while using comand prompt, but are you running it from the same folder as python script?

Comment: Are all the things the same directory? If not, `Popen`’s [`cwd` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) might help.

Comment: Never split a command line meant for the shell. Pass it as a string in both Unix and Windows.

Comment: @Howaboutnope Yes I am running the python executable from the same path as I run it from the command prompt.

Comment: @eryksun when I passed the command as a string the batchfile did not get the arguments. Hence, I used split function.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the string, but `shlex.split` and `subprocess.list2cmdline` in general don't have any clue how to quote and escape strings for the Windows cmd shell. Windows programs get a command line string, not a vector of arguments, so it's not as if we can simply use a set of rules that work for cmd.exe. It often takes some trial and error to tweak a command line to make it through both cmd.exe and the program it's running. So it won't necessarily work in Windows. In Unix, it's almost never right to use a list with `shell=True`.

Comment: On Windows we always pass a command line string. If you want to see what subprocess uses, just print `subprocess.list2cmdline(cmd)`. For `shell=True` it inserts that command line into the template `'cmd.exe /c "{}"'`. The command line is created according to VC++ `argv` rules, which are not the same as those for cmd.exe, but it's the same in the simple case of an argument with spaces in it.